# Anchor when got back

Tags: html, anchor, back

Maybe someone knows how to do such a function?

I need that every time then people goes back in my page they would get exaclty at the place where the link was, not in the top (beginnig) of a page. Facebook has such a function.

I know there is a links with anchor, but how to do this with a button back?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean when people use the back button in their browsers?

Comment: Yes, I mean browser back button. :)

Comment: It sounds like the OP want the following: when a user clicks the back button in the browser, they are scrolled back to the point they left before clicking a link to leave that page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `mysite.com/mylink.html#anchor`

Comment: Hmm.. My link looks like that: "http://www.site.com/index.php/directory/directory"

And then I write it like this: "http://www.site.com/index.php/directory/directory#anchor" it  doesnt even finds a page..

Comment: how could it be site.com/index.php/........ There should be a ? to seperate the next /, do you have rewrite rules in place?

Comment: I'm using Joomla, it change links stucture.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Function is:

> function GoBack(url){
>
> > > window.open(url,'_self');
>
> }

You can use it like this:

> <input type="button" onclick="GoBack('YourUrl#Anc')" value="Go Back" />

Answer (score 0):

You can crate a cookie named `[url of the page]` that has the value of scrollpos at the moment with javascript when a user clicks a link. And when the page loads back again, you can fetch the cookie back and scroll to that position. Ugly but does the job..